# Cannot start android service using AlaramManager in Xamarin.forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Called StartBackgroundSynchService using DependencyService.

**AlaramManager Code**

```
    public void StartBackgroundSynchService()
    {
        try
        {
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            Intent intentService = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(ReportSynchService));

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Forms.Context, 0, intentService, 0);
            am.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, DateTime.Now.Millisecond, 1000, pendingIntent);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
     }
```

**Service Class**

```
public class ReportSynchService : Service
{

    public ReportSynchService()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("In Services Constructor");
    }
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("In Services OnBind");
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("In Services OnCreate");

    }


    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("In Services OnStartCommand");
        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
    }

}
```

Alaram manager code working properly but service class not invoked.
kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: It working properly with BroadcastReceiver but not working with Service